# How to access properties of a JavaScript object using the property values of another object

Tags: javascript

Say I have these JavaScript objects:

```
questions = { name: "Age", options:[boy, girl, daddy]}
answers = {"Age" : 21, "boy" : "checked", daddy : "checked"}
```

So if I wanted to access the `"Age"` from the answers object, I would do:

```
x = answers.Age   //21
```

But how can I do the same thing but instead using the values from the questions object?

```
x = answers.questions.name   //problem
```

or

```
answers.questions.options[0]  //problem
```

As you can see I am trying to use the value of `questions.name` (`"Age"`) to access a property of answers (`Age`).

What's the right syntax or way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = answers[questions.name]
```

This works because:

```
answers.Age
```

is equivalent to:

```
answers['Age']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use indirect referencing

```
answers[questions.name]
```